# Is there a way to determine how many rows in a dataset have the same categorical variable for multiple conditions (columns)?

Tags: r, subset, categorical-data

For example,  i have the dataset below where 1 = yes and 0 = no, and I need to figure out how many calls were made by landline that lasted under 10 minutes.

[Image of example dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCL6G.png)

Comment: Your title says "multiple conditions" but your question only uses one - is your question actually more complex than stated?

Comment: In this example I want to count the number of rows (calls) that were made by landline (landline =1) where the call also lasted for under 10 minutes (under 10 minutes = 1)

Comment: Oh I see, you are using two conditions. Answer forthcoming..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sum`

```
sum(df1[, "under 10 minutes"])
```

If two columns are needed

```
colSums(df1[, c("landline", "under 10 minutes")])
```

If we are checking both columns, use `rowSums`

```
sum(rowSums(df1[, c("landline", "under 10 minutes")], na.rm = TRUE) == 2)
```

Comment: Thank you! This would work if I was only looking for the number of calls that were under 10 minutes, but I am looking for calls that were under 10 minutes and also made by landline.

Comment: @Crosby if you can update your post with `dput(exampledata)` and the expected output, it would be great

Comment: @Crosby the error could be that your column  names are different. i.e. `colnames(X919report_data)`

Comment: I retried again and made sure that the column names were identical and it worked. Thank you so much I really apprecaite the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also specifically define the values you're looking for in each column when you're finding the sum.  (This will help if you need count rows with values other than 1 in a column.)

```r
sum(df$landline == 1 & df$`under 10 minutes` == 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! For my actual problem I am working with a much larger data frame with many columns and rows, but the original question still applies. I tried the solution you provided but the out put was "[1] NA". Is this because some of the values in the data frame are "NA"? Thanks again for responding.

Comment: `sum` has the option to set `na.rm = TRUE`, as shown in akrun's answer. It is making an assumption that that is the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The `grep` function finds the rows where landline=1. We then only call those rows and `sum` the under 10 min column.

```
sum( df[ grep(1,df[,1]) ,4] )
```

Answer (score 0):

R will conveniently treat `1` and `0` as if they mean `TRUE` and `FALSE`, so we can apply logical Boolean operations like AND (`&`) and OR (`|`) on them.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 0, 1, 0), 
                 y = c(0, 0, 1, 1))

> sum(df$x & df$y)
[1] 1
> sum(df$x | df$y)
[1] 3
```

For future questions, you should look up how to use functions like `dput` or other ways to give an example data set instead of using an image.